# npm script onchange/watch only run command on files that actually changed rather than all files in a folder

Tags: npm, package.json, npm-scripts

I have following npm script in the package.json:

```json
"scripts": {
  "upload:js": "onchange \"dist/js\" -- echo {{changed}} && node sp-asset-upload.js {{changed}} 3",
  "start:message": "echo 'Watching for code changes.  Start making changes!'",
  "watch:js": "onchange -f \"add change\" \"dev/scripts/**/*.js\" -- npm-run-all clean:js buildjs:main buildjs:slick-init",
  "watch:uploadjs": "npm run upload:js",
  "watch": "npm-run-all start:message watch:js watch:uploadjs",
  "start": "npm run watch"
}
```

The `sp-asset-upload.js` is some javascript that relies on `spsave` package to upload files to SharePoint.

I am interested in uploading only the files that have recently changed, rather than all files (that may or may not have changed) in the `dist\js` folder.

I am using the `onchange` package to watch for changes. I need to basically capture the files that changed and pass that as parameter to the `sp-asset-upload.js` file instead of doing the below:

`node sp-asset-upload.ms "dist/js/*.js" 3` - *where the number parameter determines whether to upload a minor copy or major version to SharePoint.*

Can someone who might have done this share some insight?

Comment: You don't say what platform you're on but if you have the Linux `find` command available then you could use it to identify files that have been modified since the last upload.  That would at least give you a list of changed filenames each time you ran it.